# 1and1 windows hosting with asp.net

Tags: asp.net, hosting, web-hosting, trust, system.net.mail

Not sure if anyone has used 1and1 MS Hosting and encountered problems with their trust levels?

**I am simply trying to send mail using system.net.mail in asp.net (which works fine) but when its online with 1and1 I get this error:**

> Description: The application attempted
>   to perform an operation not allowed by
>   the security policy.  To grant this
>   application the required permission
>   please contact your system
>   administrator or change the
>   application's trust level in the
>   configuration file.
>
> Exception Details:
>   System.Security.SecurityException:
>   Request for the permission of type
>   'System.Net.Mail.SmtpPermission,
>   System, Version=2.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
>   failed.

I asked 1and1 and they sent me a machine.config file with their settings but no explanation with what to do with it.

Sorry I can't put up with there useless tech support any more.

Anyone got any ideas what I should do with the machine.config or something?

Comment: 1 - Move yourself away from 1and1. Seriously. 2 - Move this question to ServerFault.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

And the answer is........

1and1 do not allow access to system.net.mail.
But do however allow access the obsolete system.web.mail (oh joy)

[basic instructions with available mail server here](http://faq.1and1.com/scripting_languages_supported/asp_net/7.html)

Comment: they do now, well at least for new hosts. This test code they provided worked first time out of the box. I changed nothing but the to address and the credentials. http://faq.1and1.co.uk/scripting/asp_net/8.html

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible that your host's smtp server requries some type of authentication to relay the mail? That is all I can think of. When you instantiate the SmtpClient, try setting the [credentials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.credentials.aspx), I'm not certain what credentials you would supply, perhaps something from your hosting provider?

Answer (score 2):

You could also try modifying your web.config and changing the trust level in there.  I've had similar issues in the past with a couple of other hosts, and this worked for me:

```
<system.web>
    <trust Level="Full" />
</system.web>
```

Comment: one and one seems to not allow overides on this:

Parser Error Message: This configuration section cannot be used at this path.  This happens when the site administrator has locked access to this section using <location allowOverride="false"> from an inherited configuration file.

Comment: Yep, I think it was a long shot anyway :-)

Comment: Same happened to me when i try to send emails on 1 and 1 hosted site

Answer (score 0):

Almost any shared hosting (you only have access to a FTP site) is going to be medium trust.  Its a common limitation.  You have to develop against a medium trust server in order to weed out those issues.  Sometimes they're easy to deal with, sometimes not.

An alternative is to do virtual hosting.  You get a virtual server that you can administer yourself.  That way you can run your websites under full trust.  I do that with my 1and1 website.  While people bitch about them (what host doesn't have people bitching about it?) they have the cheapest virtual servers out there, last time I checked.

Comment: yeh but isn't system.net.mail only a medium trust proceedure? isn't this a standard way of sending mail? surely they wouldn't block this.

Comment: Medium trust means we don't trust you to get hijacked by a virus/vulnerability and start acting as a spam gateway.