# 1&1 web hosting and smtp configuration

Tags: asp.net, smtp, web-hosting

Has anyone ever tried sending emails using 1&1 smtp host? I tried the following?

```
SmtpClient mailClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.1and1.com", 587);
mailClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("admin@permias-tucson.com", "password");
```

But it always gives me a security exemption error...

I tried it using my local host and it works fine.. I tried using gmail's smtp and it worked fine as well.. It says that I need to authenticate in order to use the smtp server, I did that  by looking at the code above... Here's the exact error:

> Security Exception
>
> Description: The application attempted
>   to perform an operation not allowed by
>   the security policy.  To grant this
>   application the required permission
>   please contact your system
>   administrator or change the
>   application's trust level in the
>   configuration file.
>
> Exception Details:
>   System.Security.SecurityException:
>   Request for the permission of type
>   'System.Net.Mail.SmtpPermission,
>   System, Version=2.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
>   failed.

Comment: Perhaps you should contact 1&1 to make sure everything is setup correctly?

Comment: In the uk you need to use auth.smtp.1and1.co.uk and provide your account credentials to send email.

Comment: I did provide my credentials below that code I used...

Comment: please, copy actual error text. why people have to guess?

Comment: I assume the web page is not in 1and1 hosting. When I send using my local host, my code works, using port 587 but not port 25. My web site host is GoDaddy and they don't allow me to specify a port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to authenticate to send SMTP mail (Point 2a from their [FAQ](http://faq.1and1.com/e_mail/setting_up_email_clients_like_ms_outlook_outlook_express_and_netscape_mail_/17.html))

Comment: problem is how can I authenticate ?

Comment: I understand authenticate just means to provide username and password in the smtp and I did that from the code above

Comment: googling specifically for '1and1 system.net.mail' throws up lots of people with the same problem and this SO post from a few months ago http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1915032/1and1-windows-hosting-with-asp-net "1and1 do not allow access to system.net.mail"

Comment: Try auth.smtp.1and1.com instead of smtp.1and1.com

Comment: 1and1 do support system.net.mail (well, for new hosts at least). This sample code worked first time http://faq.1and1.co.uk/scripting/asp_net/8.html

Answer (score 1):

My client has a new hosting from 1and1.com, and the thing that worked for me was to remove the port number and it working. 1and1 provided me a reference link http://help.1and1.com/hosting-c37630/scripts-and-programming-languages-c85099/aspnet-c39624/send-an-e-mail-using-aspnet-a604246.html

My code:

```
SmtpClient objSmtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.1and1.com");
objSmtp.EnableSsl = true;
objSmtp.Credentials = new   
System.Net.NetworkCredential("mail@email.org", "PWD");
```

Answer (score 0):

also just ensure that your reverse (PTR) maps back to you... otherwise alot of SMTP servers will reject you.